# How do you do a true pattern search in jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery

I have multilple `<select>` named: taskDESCRIPTION-,taskDESCRIPTION-1,taskDESCRIPTION-2,...
I want to match all but the first?

```
$('#details form[name=aform]').find('select[name^=taskDESCRIPTION-] :selected,input:text').each(function () {

  //my validation

}
```

**Updated:**  True pattern search is currently not possible within the jQuery selector.

Comment: IMHO, a cleaner way would be to add a class to all the inputs which should be validated, and select them with a `$('#details form[name=aform]').find('.needsValidation')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`gt`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector, which is **zero based** if you want exclude the first that appears *in the dom*:

```
$('#details form[name=aform]').find('select[name^=taskDESCRIPTION-]:gt(0):selected,input:text').each(function () {

      //my validation

}
```

If you want to exclude the first one meaning, you want the one that's **not** `1`, you can use the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$('#details form[name=aform]').find('select[name^=taskDESCRIPTION-]:not(select[name=taskDESCRIPTION-1]):selected,input:text').each(function () {

      //my validation

}
```

Comment: Mind you, this will ignore the first `taskDESCRIPTION-` that *appears in the DOM,* which may not be the one named `taskDESCRIPTION-`

Comment: @shaun5 Check my updated edit, is that what you mean? If not, can you further clarify?

Comment: @Blazemonger Good shout, added an alternative for that too.

Comment: Using `:not` is a working solution. Thanks. I guess the reason I couldn't get a true pattern search to work is that it is currently not possible...

Answer (score 1):

You can't do proper pattern matching, as far as I'm aware. At some point you're going to have to filter down that set of elements.

If they appear in that order in the DOM then you can simply ignore the first matching element, using the [`:gt`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector:

```
$(...).find('select[name^=taskDESCRIPTION-]:gt(0) ...');
```

If they're not so nicely ordered, then you'll have to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery/com/filter/) to check that the `name` attribute contains a number:

```
$(...).find('select[name^="taskDESCRIPTION-"]').filter(function(i, element) {
    return /taskDESCRIPTION-\d+/.test(element.getAttribute("name"));
});
```